# Bash array variable into single space elements

Tags: arrays, bash, scripting

I'm trying to print a word from variable with multiple elements using array. Here is a script:

```
location=($(here mysql query to extract name of locations))
for i in "${location[@]}"; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

But these location name contains spaces: `MUMBAI - BORIVALI`, `DELHI - LAJPATNAGAR` and so on. So it prints like: Output in debug mode:

```
   + for i in '"${LOCATION[@]}"'
+ echo DELHI
DELHI
+ for i in '"${LOCATION[@]}"'
+ echo -
-
+ for i in '"${LOCATION[@]}"'
+ echo LAJPATNAGAR
LAJPATNAGAR
+ for i in '"${LOCATION[@]}"'
+ echo MUMBAI
MUMBAI
+ for i in '"${LOCATION[@]}"'
+ echo -
-
+ for i in '"${LOCATION[@]}"'
+ echo BORIVLI
BORIVLI
```

I've tried with double quotes:

```
location=("$(here mysql query to extract name of locations)")
```

then output is

```
+ for i in '"${LOCATION[@]}"'
+ echo 'DELHI - LAJPATNAGAR
MUMBAI - BORIVLI'
```

together.

I want output:

```
+ echo 'DELHI - LAJPATNAGAR'
DELHI - LAJPATNAGAR
+ echo 'MUMBAI - BORIVLI'
MUMBAI - BORIVLI
```

Comment: Your edit shows commas between fields, is that correct?  In that case you can set `IFS` to a comma.  Please ensure that you show *exactly* what is produced by mysql.

Comment: @cdarke commas only in the question to show different location name

Comment: Your new edit shows hyphens between the fields, is that correct?

Comment: Why don't we eliminate the guessing and you post the first 10-lines of `$(here mysql query to extract name of locations)`?

Comment: yes there is hyphens and mysql query only contains the name of table and conditions. You can consider `MUMBAI - BORIVLI` and `DELHI - LAJPATNAGAR` as different value in column for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the locations don't contain newlines, you can try

```
while read -r location ; do
    echo "$location"
done < <(mysql ...)
```

`read` reads line by line if given just one parameter. By default, it reads from stdin, but with process substitution, we redirected output of the `mysql` command to it.

Comment: @Lnux: Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting IFS to newline-only:

```
IFS="$(echo)"
location=($(here mysql query to extract name of locations))
for i in "${location[@]}"; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Example with `test.txt`:

```
A B C
D E
F
```

Run the above code, replacing the MySQL query with `cat test.txt`. Output:

```
A B C
D E
F
```

If you drop the `IFS="$(echo)"` line, you will get each letter on a separate line.

Comment: No wait. .. the actual name of locations are different. Let me modify the questions. Its not llike 1 2

Comment: @Lnux Then just group them by three. If the number of spaces are not the same across all names, you're out of luck or need some other tricks.

Comment: @Lnux Updated and changed to another solution.

Comment: Output is still together

Answer (score 0):

Just count 3 fields:

```
location=($(here mysql query to extract name of locations))

for ((i=0; i <= ${#location}; i+=3))
do
    echo "${location[i]} ${location[i+1]} ${location[i+2]}"
done
```